# Is it a problem if my laptop is out of battery when I'm asked to switch it on?

Tags: airport-security, turkey, electronic-items

The airports in Turkey have additional security at entry and the guards often ask passengers to switch on the laptops. They just want to see the splash screen.

I haven't had any problem so far, but I will shortly travel (from Istanbul Atatürk Airport) with a laptop whose battery is not in good health.

Would it be a problem if my laptop is out of battery when I'm asked to switch it on?

Comment: Get a new battery.  That will solve you any unnecessary delays or problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, potentially.

For flights to the US (and potentially other destinations), [you may not be allowed to travel with an electronic device in your carry-on that you cannot turn on](http://www.latimes.com/travel/deals/la-trb-tsa-tighter-security-20140707-story.html):

> Under new TSA rules, if you do so when returning to the U.S. from abroad, you'd better keep your charger or mobile battery pack in your carry-on bag — or risk having your electronic devices confiscated.
>
> Travelers on direct flights to the U.S. from some overseas airports (which ones aren't specified) must be able to power up devices when they go through airport security. "Powerless devices will not be permitted onboard the aircraft," the Transportation Security Administration announced in a release Sunday. "The traveler may also undergo additional screening."

If you carry the charger with you, you may be able to plug the laptop in and charge it up some in the event that the battery dies. I would not carry a device that cannot be turned on.

Comment: It's sad that LA times is unavailable in EU.

Comment: @gdrt Oh sorry that's awful. I added the pertinent section to the answer.